# Use both arrayformula and filter in google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet document with two sheets. Columns A is the name of a person. Rest of columns are informations about the person.
Using arrayformula() I "copied" column A of sheet1 to column A of sheet2 (so it updates automatically as soon as I add someone in the list).
All columns of sheet1 have filters so I can sort easily.

In the 2nd sheet I have other infos about the persons.
Now my problem is that when I sort from A-Z for instance, all info in sheet1 are sorted aswell. But in sheet2 they are all messed up.

I search for workarounds but didn't find any yet. I continue searching but I hope someone can help me here :)

Thanks for your answers !
(I can prepare a special sheet to show you my problem if you want)

Here is my doc so you can see what's wrong :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YyVS-hRQ1s1H8hY_D8sr9_judYuGMtmhS1Algp-ESus/edit#gid=0

Comment: Only INDEX/MATCH might help. Apart from that, Try absolute references like $A$1 instead of A1 . It'll help a bit, but,i don't think it'll solve anything.

Comment: Tnx I'll try this and keep you up to date :)

Comment: I would use `vlookup` (which works well with arrayformula) to pull information about every person from the other sheet, regardless of how it's sorted.